# npm install failed by gyp verb could not find "msbuild.exe" in PATH - finding location in registry

Tags: node.js, vue.js, installation, msbuild, gyp

I encounter this problem when I execute `npm install` command

I tried to add the MSBuild.exe to PATH but can't success

How can I process this problem?

Before I have added to the python2 PATH,and tried `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

```
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\fzc\.node-gyp\16.5.0
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "msbuild.exe" in PATH - finding location in registry
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\fzc\code\nx-admin\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\fzc\\code\\nx-admin\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\fzc\code\nx-admin\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.5.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, running `npm i -g windows-build-tools` from a command line with administrator privileges would hang during installation, but I was able to navigate to `C:\Users\[username]\.windows-build-tools` and run `vs_BuildTools.exe` file from there. This worked its magic, and I was able to run `npm install` as normal.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a node and npm version issue, on node v14 it worked for me.